# Somewhat versatile usage of \@gobble and \@firstofone found in several macros

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, primitives, detokenize

I was doing search about my question (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/250053/revisions) for more detail) and found a thread [commath and \ifinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner). In the thread, there is a macro named `\spx` , the definition and usage of which are extracted below. Since we can see `{^{#1}}` in the definition, it seems to be an improved `^`. I understand that `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}` determines whether `#1` is empty or not, but I cannot understand how the rest of this `\if`-clause functions. Additionally, there are some threads where similar `\if`-clause can be found (e.g. [Writing musical pitches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148355/writing-musical-pitches), [Table without counting ampersands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124035/table-without-counting-ampersands) and so on).

What function does this kind of `\if`-clause have and what is the difference between `\spx` and plain `^`?

```
% ----- definition of \spx and its usage -----
\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
        \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {^{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer the questions backwards, the difference is that `\spx{}` expands to nothing whereas `^{}` produces an empty superscript atom. Such an empty superscript field is not equivalent to not having a superscript, and can affect the position of a subscript on the same base.

```
  \expandafter\@gobble
\else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{^{#1}}%
```

removes the `{^{#1}` from the input stream in the true case as the `\expandafter` expands the `\else` which removes everything up to `\fi`
so the following expansion is of `\@gobble{^#1}` which is nothing.

Similarly in the false branch you need `\expandafter` to remove the `\fi` and then `\@firstofone` to remove the outer braces, so expanding `\@firstofone{^{#1}}` which is `^{#1}`

Comment: Why do we need these two `\expandafter`? Is it undesirable to replace `\expandafter\@gobble` by `\empty` and `\expandafter\@firstofone` by `^#1` and then to delete `{^{#1}}`?

Comment: I tried revising the macro like the comment above. The output of `x\spx{}=x` apparently seems to be the same as that of `x=x` and also `2\spx{2}=4` as `2^2=4`.

Comment: @Merzong in this case it is possibly safe to do that but it means that the `^{#1}` is executed inside the `\if` which means that any code in that argument has to be slightly careful about how it exposes any `\fi` tokens, and also any code inside `#1` if it looks ahead with `\@ifnextchar` or `\futurelet` etc would see `\fi` rather than the next natural token. Rather than worry about whether that matters in each case most latex code just always uses the `\expandafter` form.

Comment: I vaguely understood why I should use the `\expandafter` form, but I cannot come up with the concrete case that may cause unintended behaviors.

Comment: @Merzong see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107753/why-the-expandafter-firstoftwo-idiom

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is very intelligible with its minute explanation of expansion process. Thank you for giving a good example.